# Proper shopify api product create

Tags: php, curl, shopify

I am trying to create product with shopify api but product is not set and I am getting no errors. `print_r($server_output);` displays nothing so I can't see where I am wrong. curl is also enabled. Below is the code that I use.
When I `print_r($products);` it displays array how it should. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$name='test product 555';
$group=36;
$quantity=20;
$price='20.95';

$url = 'https://my_key_and_pass/admin/products.json';
$type = 'POST';
$product = array('title' => utf8_encode($name),
        'body_html' => utf8_encode($name),
        'product_type'=> $group,
        'variants' => array(
        array('price' => $price,
        'inventory_quantity'=> $quantity,
        'inventory_management' => 'shopify'
        )
        )
        );

$ch = curl_init($url);
$data_string = json_encode(array('product'=>$product));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Maybe describe what you expect, and what you get instead?

Comment: You should use node.js instead.

Comment: ha! screw node.js that is for amateurs. Use Fortran instead and be a real man. These people using pussy scripting languages... pffft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that host didn't have SSL enabled so this code resolved it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with PHP/curl, but you might be missing the post field count:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data_string));
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

since you have only one product.

Have you tried in an app like Postman? does it work there?